# Where can I find this theorem or how can I prove it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H\lhd G$, $[G: H] = p$, $p$ prime. Then the number of conjugates with an element $x$ in $H$ is $n$ or $n/p$, where $n$ is the number of conjugates with $x$ in $G$.

I try to  Consider $|HC_G(x)|$ and the transitivity of index but i do know how. Help me please.

Comment: For awhile I could not figure out what `number of conjugates with elements x in H is n` was supposed to mean. I eventually figured out it means "there are $n$ elements obtained by conjugating $x$ by elements in $H$."

Comment: es it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X_G(x)$ denote the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$. What you're trying to say is that if $\#X_G(x)=n$ then we can conclude that $\#X_H(x)$ is either $n$ or $n/p$.

Now by orbit-stabilizer, $\#X_G(x)=|G/C_G(x)|$. So the desired conclusion is

$$\{n,n/p\}\ni\frac{|H|}{|C_H(x)|}=\frac{|H|}{|G|}\frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_H(x)|}=\frac{n}{p}\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_H(x)|}$$

or equivalently (via intersection index formula $[A:A\cap B]=[AB:B]$)

$$\{1,p\}\ni\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_H(x)|}=\frac{|C_G(x)|}{|C_G(x)\cap H|}=\frac{|C_G(x)H|}{|H|}$$

But $C_G(x)H$ lies between $H$ and $G$ so...

Comment: yes but where i can introduce the transivity of index

Comment: @Knight Transitivity comes in play in $1=[H:H]\mid[G_G(x)H:H]\mid[G:H]=p$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for more clarity :)